# Change For expression to lambda Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

I want to change this expression from this for loop to a lambda expression using java 8 and I want to return the number position in the array that match with that value.

```
String[] values= {"VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3"};

int stringIndex;
for(stringIndex = 0; stringIndex < values.length; stringIndex++)
    if(stringWithValue.contains(values[stringIndex])) break;
```

For example,

`stringWithValue = "SomeOtherThingVALUE1"` should return **0** and so on with the other values.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Your loop doesn't actually do anything.  What is the goal of the loop?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the loop actually checks for matching and `break` if found. The value of `stringIndex` can be used outside the loop to check the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

To be honest, I'm not sure it is any better than your loop.

```
import java.util.stream.*;

public class LambdaDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringWithValue = "xxxxxxxVALUE2xxxxxxx";
        String[] values= {"VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3"};

        int stringIndex = IntStream
                .range(0, values.length)
                .filter(i -> stringWithValue.contains(values[i]))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseGet(() -> -1);
        
        System.out.println(stringIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `.orElse(-1)` (or `.orElse(values.length)` to match the behavior of the loop)? Using `orElseGet` here has no advantage.

Comment: thank you Chris Foley, I really appreciate it. Best regards

Comment: @EdgarTorres  If this is indeed the answer you were looking for then you should accept it.

Comment: Yes, it worked great! that was what I was trying without success. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> Change For expression to Lambda.

Lambdas are constructed from a variety of functional interfaces.  In your case you need a [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) that takes a String Array and a String as arguments and returns an Integer.

```
String[] values = { "VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3" };
 
BiFunction<String[], String, Integer> getIndex =
        (arr, val) -> IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                .filter(i -> val.contains(arr[i])).findFirst()
                .orElse(-1);

int i = getIndex.apply(values,"SomeOtherThingVALUE3");
System.out.println(i);      
i = getIndex.apply(values,"Hello");
System.out.println(i);
```

Prints

```
2
-1
```